# How make the form password data hidden in Chrome developer tools network pannel when login.do submit?

Tags: java, html, forms, submit, form-submit

When the normal log-in in simple html form submitting,
Chrome Developer Tools "Network" panel showing form data like this

[image]

But at the major sites like Facebook, Google...
They don't show form data in network panel like this

[image]

How can do that? Is there any example or tutorials?

Comment: That is completely impossible.  (you can hash in JS, but the client can still see the password) You're looking at the wrong request.

Comment: SLaks is entirely correct. For facebook, filter to the request to login.php, and check out the form data there. There is a value called "pass". It's obviously hashed, but it's there.

Comment: Related: [Username and password stored under form data in Chrome Dev Tools](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/51186).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We cannot hide from the developer network tab or the form data shown and no one else can see once the network tab clears after a new page is loaded. Once SSL is enabled, That is when the domain is HTTPS the data transferred will be encrypted based on the SSL certificate that could be decrypted at the server end.

Normally, HTTPS protocol is built on TLS/SSL to encrypt the data that is transmitted over the network and to ensure that user is being sent towards the desired site.

If you need you can check the following websites. The username and the password will be shown in the network tab.

- https://www.facebook.com
- https://twitter.com/login
- https://www.linkedin.com

Hence, I hope there is no need of doing this. Anyway if you are looking for an encryption at the client end, then use public key at the client to encrypt and use a private key at the server end as well.

Comment: I saw a bank website encrypted the password value when I opened the developer console, so it is really needed'

Comment: Just tried this on facebook and the password is already encrypted in dev tools

Comment: so this goes back to the question - how then do we encrypt it in the dev tools ?